# При попытке изменить картинку в PictureBox вылетает ошибка

Tags: c#, winforms

При потытке изменить изображение на форме `Form2` через форму `Form1` вылетает ошибка System.NullReferenceException:

> Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.

Вот код Form1

```
namespace CarGames
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        FormLevel1 parentForm;
 
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
 
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            parentForm.pictureBox11.Image = Properties.Resources._2;
        }
    }
}
```

В `Form2` ничего кроме `PictureBox` нету.
Переход между формам осуществляется через ещё одну форму.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Уважаемый Киса, весь ли код Вы привели? Где у Вас инициализируется parentForm.pictureBox11.Image ? Где конструктор FormLevel1(...) ?

Answer (score 1):

В вашем коде нигде не инициализируется `parentForm`.

Добавьте параметр в конструктор. Это может выглядеть примерно так:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    readonly FormLevel1 _parentForm;

    public Form1(FormLevel1 parentForm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _parentForm = parentForm;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _parentForm.PictureBoxCar.Image = Properties.Resources.Car2;
    }
}
```

Если я правильно понимаю, эта форма создаётся и вызывается где-то в коде родительской формы `FormLevel1`. Добавьте в вызов ссылку на текущий экземпляр: `new Form1(this)`.

Answer (score 0):

> Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.

означает что ваш ресурс `= null`. Проверьте верно ли указан ресурс, или получите из ресурсов картинку в переменную и после присвойте её `PictureBox`

Comment: У автора parentForm равно null.